# Replace $variable which changes every iteration in while loop

Tags: regex, perl

I have two input files: `filea` and `fileb`. In `filea`, I have a string `$pc_count$`, where in `fileb`, there are numbers and strings. I have to search numbers in `fileb` and replace `$pc_count$` in `filea`.

I have tried the code below, but the first value of `fileb` is repeated (`$pc_count$`) every time.

```
open (IN_FILE, "<filea") or die "Please provide an correct file path\n";
open (IN_FILE1, "<fileb") or die "Please provide an correct file path\n";
my $i = 0;
while (<IN_FILE>) {
        if($_ =~ /\$pc_count\$/) {
                my $line = $_;
                while (<IN_FILE1>) {

                        if($_ =~ /([a-z0-9-]+)[\s]+/) {
                                my $first = $1; 
                                $line =~ s/\$pc_count\$/$first/;
                                #print OUT_FILE("$line");
                                print $line;

                        }

                }

        }
        #print OUT_FILE("$_");
}
close IN_FILE;
close IN_FILE1;
```

**filea**

```
case(pc)
    'h$pc_count$ : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
endcase
```

**fileb**

```
fe0000
fe0001
fe0002
fe0003
..
..
..
```

**Result:**

```
case(pc)
    'hfe000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
    'hfe000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
    'hfe000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
    'hfe000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..  
endcase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first substitution, `$line` is changed, and it no longer has the string `$pc_count$`.  One way to fix this is to keep a copy of the original line in another variable (`$line2`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (IN_FILE, "<filea") or die "Please provide an correct file path\n";
open (IN_FILE1, "<fileb") or die "Please provide an correct file path\n";
my $i = 0;

while (<IN_FILE>) {
        if ($_ =~ /\$pc_count\$/) {
                my $line = $_;
                while (<IN_FILE1>) {
                        my $line2 = $line;
                        if ($_ =~ /([a-z0-9-]+)[\s]+/) {
                                my $first = $1; 
                                $line2 =~ s/\$pc_count\$/$first/;
                                print $line2;
                        }
                }
        }
        #print OUT_FILE("$_");
}
close IN_FILE;
close IN_FILE1;
```

Output:

```
'hfe0000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0001 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0002 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0003 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

[I had to fix a syntax error in your code before I could run it. Please ensure that you give us runnable code.]

The problem is what is stored in `$line`.

You iterate through your `IN_FILE` filehandle until your find a line containing `$pc_count$`. You then copy that line into `$line` and go into the inner processing loop.

So the first time round your inner loop, `$line` contains:

```
'h$pc_count$ : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
```

A couple of lines later, you change `$line` using this code:

```
$line =~ s/\$pc_count\$/$first/;
```

So `$line` now contains:

```
'hfe000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
```

The next time around your loop, you start with `$line` containing the string that starts with `hfe000`. So when you try to run your substitution a second time, nothing changes because `$line` no longer contains `$pc_count$`.

The easiest fix is probably not to change `$line` at all, but to directly print the output from the substitution (and to use `/r` so the original string isn't altered).

```
if($_ =~ /([a-z0-9-]+)[\s]+/) {
    my $first = $1;
    print $line =~ s/\$pc_count\$/$first/r;
}
```

Which produces:

```
'hfe0000 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0001 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0002 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
'hfe0003 : $display("checkdata string %s ",pc_string);
```